# Java: non-static variable value cannot be referenced from a static context error

Tags: java, static

I am writing a code in 2 separate classes that takes a temp as 2 separate variables and prints it out and then runs conversion methods to get temps in other scales. I keep getting the error non-static variable value cannot be referenced from a static context in the Temperature.java part of my code because of the variables being in the constructor which is not static. The whole concept is a bit confusing to me and I'd love any input on hope static and non-static works and how you can switch between them without issue.

code as follows:

```
public class Temperature
{
  int value = 50;
  String scale = "F";

   public Temperature(int value, String scale){
    value = value;
    scale = scale;
   }

  public static void value(int value){
    int number;
  }
  public static boolean scale(String scale){
    if (scale == "C"){
      return true;
    }
    else if (scale == "F"){
      return true;
    }
    else if (scale == "K"){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static void convertToCelsius(int value, String scale){
    if (scale == "F"){
      int newValue = (5/9) * (value - 32);
      System.out.println("The equivalent tempurature is " + newValue + "C");
    }
    else if (scale == "K"){
      double newValue = value - 273.15;
      System.out.println("The equivalent tempurature is " + newValue + "C");
    }
    else{
    }
  }

   public static void convertToFarenheit(int Value, String scale){
    if (scale == "C"){
      int newValue = ((9/5) * (value + 32));
      System.out.println("The equivalent tempurature is " + newValue + "F");
    }
    else if (scale == "K"){
      int newValue = ((9/5) * (value - 273) + 32);
      System.out.println("The equivalent tempurature is " + newValue + "F");
    }
    else{
    }
  }

    public static void convertToKelvin(int value, String scale){
    if (scale == "F"){
      int newValue = ((5/9) * (value - 32) + 273);
      System.out.println("The equivalent tempurature is " + newValue + "C");
    }
    if (scale == "C"){
      double newValue = (value + 273.15);
      System.out.println("The equivalent tempurature is " + newValue + "C");
    }
    else{
    }
  }      
  }
```

for the main method the code is in the separate class as follows:

```
public class UsingTemperature
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Temperature t = new Temperature(50, "F");//declaring an object
  System.out.println(t);

  // Test out conversions:
  System.out.println("Test out conversions:");
  // F to C
  t.convertToCelsius();
  System.out.println(t);

  // C to F
  t.convertToFahrenheit();
  System.out.println(t);

  // F to K
  t.convertToKelvin();
  System.out.println(t);

  // K to F
  t.convertToFahrenheit();
  System.out.println(t);

  // F to K:
  t.convertToKelvin();
  System.out.println(t);

  // K to C
  t.convertToCelsius();
  System.out.println(t);

  // C to K
  t.convertToKelvin();
  System.out.println(t); 
 }

}
```

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Static refers to something that be accessed outside of a class without the creation of an object.

Comment: Thank you jhobbie! That is a great clear and simple way of putting it

Comment: btw you have a ton of integer division issues here

Comment: Did you try searching for ["non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22non-static+variable+cannot+be+referenced+from+a+static+context%22+is%3Aquestion) on this site?  There are a number of possible duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the Static Modifier in your methods, these methods will exist independently of any instances created for the class.
So in your class Temperature your static methods:

- Exist before you make a new instance of Temperature
- There is just one copy of your static methods, regardless of the number of instances of  Temperature you have.

Besides, I think that you only want Temperature as a utility, so the constructor makes no sense because a constructor is used only to create instances

When you need to use methods from Temperature: Temperature.name_method(params)

Comment: That is actually a great point. I had been suggested to use a constructor but it seems maybe without would simplify things a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`t` is an object, but all of your `convertToScale` methods are static. Use `Temperature.convertToScale(t.value, t.scale)`

Also,

```
t.convertToCelsius();
System.out.println(t);
```

probably does not do what you expect it to do. None of your `convertToScale` methods are mutators (they just print stuff), so calling `t.convertToCelsius()` only prints out what the conversion does, then `System.out.println(t)` would print the default object.toString() (which gives you @0012378 or something)

Also, I just noticed all of the `(5/9)` and `(9/5)` you have, which will almost certainly break the math as given, due to how integer division works. Explicitly declare one of them as a double with 5.0 or 5d

Comment: That is a great idea for the main but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem in the other methods

Comment: @user3889083 What other problems? Your question only asks about 'cannot refer to non-static...'

Comment: What I mean is that even replacing those did not solve the initial issues of the static/nonstatic